# Lisp if not nil

Tags: if-statement, null, lisp

I'm trying to do a simple `if` statement that checks if a variable is `nil` or not.

```
(defun test (input)
  (let ((testvar (first input)))
   (if (not nil testvar)
    (do this)
    (do that))))
```

Could anyone explain the proper syntax to me?

Comment: Just `(if (not testvar) ...)`. Or put the true branch first and do `(if testvar ...)`.

Answer (score 26):

Since `nil` is equivalent to the boolean value `false`, there is no need to compare to it explicitly.

A simple

```
(if testvar
  (...)
  (...))
```

will do the job. You only need `not` if you want to check for the opposite, e.g. if you want to check that a variable is not `nil`:

```
(if (not testvar)
  (...)
  (...))
```

Apart from that, there is also a predicate function called [`null`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_null.htm) that you might use. It is basically meant for checking whether a given list is empty, but since the empty list is equivalent to `nil`, it will work (as the examples on the linked page point out):

```
(null '()) =>  T
(null nil) =>  T
(null t) =>  NIL
(null 1) =>  NIL
```

Anyway, this basically only moves the problem one layer up ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to check if the variable is nil or if it is not nil?

For not nil: `(if v ... ...)`

For nil: `(if (not v) ... ...)`

There are (in CL) many variations which are all logically the same but may indicate intent better: `(if (null v) ... ...)` if the same as the second case above but might indicate to the reader that you are looking for `()‘ instead of logical falsity (ie an empty list). And there are plenty of other variations.

Answer (score 0):

jkiiski was right:

Just (if (not testvar) ...). Or put the true branch first and do (if testvar ...)

Comment: A stylistic comment:  If testvar is "intended" to be a boolean, then `(if testvar ...)` and `(if (not testvar) ...)` are the way to go, in my opinion.  If testvar is some other kind of value that might just happen to be nil, then you might use `(if (not (null testvar)) ...)` and `(if (null testvar) ..)`.  The compiler should probably optimize them to be the same, but it may make the code easier to read for someone else.